# Amazon S3 redirect based on browser language

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've a multi language website. I want to redirect english users to /en and spanish users to /es.

Currently I'm doing it via Javascript, but I feel there is a better way.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    if (["es","en"].indexOf(language) != -1){
        window.location.replace(language);    
    }
    else{
        // other languages go to en
        window.location.replace("/en");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the title say, I want to know how to do it using Amazon S3 Web hosting server, thus Amazon Cloud Front. Your answer  is related to other webserver like Apache, Nginx, etc...